# What are the "@", "[", "]" used for in excel worksheet formulas

Tags: excel

I have purchased Microsoft office 2013 and I downloaded the new amortization template. One of the formulas has "[", "]" and a "@" sign in it. I and wondering whats the significants of it in that formula. This will help me to understand whats going on. The complete formula is.

```
=IF([@[PMT NO]]<>"",SUM(INDEX([INTEREST],1,1):[@INTEREST]),"")
```

The link to the file is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81707637/Loan%20amortization%20schedule1.xlsx)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please read here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx and @LukeZ answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are dynamic references to the current value in the column listed.

`PMT NO` is a column in the table.  Therefore, `[@[PMT NO]]` will dynamically resolve to the value of the cell in the PMT NO column for that row.

If you highlight one of the cells that has this formula, and then click within the formula bar, it should color-code these variables as well as the border around the specific cell that it references.

[image]

Comment: Can This be done in excel 2003 with lists?